create heatmap with only 2 colors
I have a dataset that looks like this:
profession     Australia_F   Australia_M      Canada_F      Canada_M    Kenya_F   Kenya_M
Author         20            80               55            34          60        23
Librarian      10            34               89            33          89        12
Pilot          78            12               67            90          12        55

I want to plot a sort of heatmap with these values. I tried this:
melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Profession', var_name='Country_Gender', value_name='Number')



melted_df[['Country', 'Gender']] = melted_df['Country_Gender'].str.split('_', expand=True)
melted_df['Number'] = pd.to_numeric(melted_df['Number'], errors='coerce')

heatmap_data = melted_df.pivot_table(index='Profession', columns=['Country', 'Gender'], values='Number')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))  
sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, cmap='coolwarm', annot=True, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.5)
plt.xlabel('Country and Gender')  
plt.ylabel('Profession')  
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  
plt.tight_layout()  
plt.savefig('heatmap.png')

and it seems to work but currently it assigns different colors to all cells based on the numerical value. However, I only want 2 colors in my chart: red & blue.
what I want is that for each profession (each row), I compare each country's F vs M values and color the higher value cell in red.
For example, for Author, these three cells should be red:
Australia_M  (80)
Canada_F (55)
Kenya_F (60)
while the other 3 in that row should be blue. How can I achieve this?

You can use two different dataframes for the coloring and for the text annotations. Creating a copy of the original dataframe, compare the even and the odd columns creates a dataframe of booleans. These booleans (internal values 0 for False and 1 for True) then decide the coloring.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = {'Profession': ['Author', 'Librarian', 'Pilot'],
        'Australia_F': [20, 10, 78],
        'Australia_M': [80, 34, 12],
        'Canada_F': [55, 89, 67],
        'Canada_M': [34, 33, 90],
        'Kenya_F': [60, 89, 12],
        'Kenya_M': [23, 12, 55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Profession')
df_coloring = df.copy()
for colF, colM in zip(df_coloring.columns[::2], df_coloring.columns[1::2]):
    df_coloring[colF] = df[colF] > df[colM]
    df_coloring[colM] = df[colM] > df[colF]

sns.set_style('white')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
sns.heatmap(df_coloring, cmap='coolwarm', annot=df, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.5, cbar=False)
plt.xlabel('Country and Gender')
plt.ylabel('Profession')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Optionally, you could add extra separations, put the gender at the top and the country at the bottom:
sns.set_style('white')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = sns.heatmap(df_coloring, cmap='coolwarm', annot=df, fmt=".0f", linewidths=.5, cbar=False, annot_kws={"size": 22})
countries = [l.get_text()[:-2] for l in ax.get_xticklabels()[::2]]
ax_top = ax.secondary_xaxis('top')
ax_top.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks(), [l.get_text()[-1:] for l in ax.get_xticklabels()])
ax_top.tick_params(length=0)
ax.set_xticks(range(1, len(df.columns), 2), countries)

for i in range(0, len(df.columns) + 1, 2):
    ax.axvline(i, lw=4, color='white')
for i in range(0, len(df) + 1):
    ax.axhline(i, lw=4, color='white')
ax.set_xlabel('Country and Gender')
ax.set_ylabel('Profession')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



this works well but I have a follow-up question. How do i remove the decimals .0? Especially in case where certain cells have a NaN. I want whole numbers.

You could replace fmt=".1f" with fmt=".0f" to get zero decimals.  You can further add annot_kws={"size":14} if you want to change the fontsize.

Could you also add a bit more on how to add customized colors (using rgb codes). Are these both colors from the cmap='coolwarm' theme? because otherwise i only see "white" in the code

These are the highest and lowest colors of the 'coolwarm' colormap. You can use e.g. cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['#2c7bb6', '#d7191c']) for custom colors. See also matplotlib colors.

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = {
    'Profession': ['Author', 'Librarian', 'Pilot'],
    'Australia_F': [20, 10, 78],
    'Australia_M': [80, 34, 12],
    'Canada_F': [55, 89, 67],
    'Canada_M': [34, 33, 90],
    'Kenya_F': [60, 89, 12],
    'Kenya_M': [23, 12, 55]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Profession', var_name='Country_Gender', value_name='Number')
melted_df[['Country', 'Gender']] = melted_df['Country_Gender'].str.split('_', expand=True)
melted_df['Number'] = pd.to_numeric(melted_df['Number'], errors='coerce')
def assign_color(row):
    if row['Gender'] == 'F':
        return 'red' if row['Number'] > melted_df[(melted_df['Profession'] == row['Profession']) & (melted_df['Country'] == row['Country']) & (melted_df['Gender'] == 'M')]['Number'].values[0] else 'blue'
    else:
        return 'red' if row['Number'] > melted_df[(melted_df['Profession'] == row['Profession']) & (melted_df['Country'] == row['Country']) & (melted_df['Gender'] == 'F')]['Number'].values[0] else 'blue'
melted_df['Color'] = melted_df.apply(assign_color, axis=1)
heatmap_data = melted_df.pivot_table(index='Profession', columns=['Country', 'Gender'], values='Number')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))  
sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, cmap='coolwarm', annot=True, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.5, cbar=False, square=True, mask=heatmap_data.isna(), annot_kws={"fontsize":10}, center=50)
plt.xlabel('Country and Gender')  
plt.ylabel('Profession')  
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  
plt.tight_layout()  
plt.savefig('heatmap.png')


have you run this code? it runs multiple colors and shades. i only wanted 2.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
